# Run bluetooth tethering script after login or at boot

Tags: boot, script

I want my RP to initiate PANU mode connection (BT tethering) to my phone. The script should start at boot or after login so it won't hang the booting. I created the following script that works perfectly when launched manually:

```
#!/bin/sh

test-network <BT address> nap &
```

Where do I place the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper solution would be to create a SystemD service, as described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). Create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/bt_tether.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=BT Tethering service
Requires=bluetooth.service
After=bluetooth.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/full/path/to/test-network <BT address> nap
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run the following command as root:

```
systemctl enable bt_tether.service
```

Comment: I've tried writing a script with a simple command (run a bluez test script) and placed it in bashrc: 'test-network <BT address> nap' It works, it starts after login and if the tethering mode is enabled on my phone, it connects. I like your solution, it's more elegant!

Comment: Anything you put in `.bashrc` is executed every time you login or open a new shell. If you don't mind if that command gets executed several times, it's OK.

Comment: Is there a way to launch the command after network is found not available? I guess something with network-online.target ... In other words, if there's no network available on eth0 and wlan0, launch the command.